# Deleting large folders on remote machines

Tags: java, optimization, performance

I am trying to delete a large folders (with many levels of subfolders) over a network (i.e, on a remote machine).

I have the following code and it takes 10 minutes. Is there a way to improve this drastically?

```
public static boolean deleteDirectory(File directory) {

        File[] files = directory.listFiles(); // Value is null if the file is not an directory or if the file doesn't exist
        if(null!=files && files.length>0){
            //Gets in here only if the file is directory
            long filesCount = files.length;
            for(int i=0; i<filesCount; i++) {
                deleteDirectory(files[i]);
            }
        }
        return(directory.delete());
    }
```

Comment: Do you have command line access to the machines? Because it would probably be faster to have the OS do it with `rmdir`/`rm -rf` in a `Runtime.exec()` if so.

Comment: @MrLore The remote machine can run on windows or linux or something else too. Will this still help ?

Comment: In that case it would be a bit of a hassle as you'd have to write different commands for each, or a big if block.

Answer (score 2):

I decide to write my own function(using native process) to delete the files(tested on **windows**), no external dependencies on jars.

Implementation details for windows:

- I am using [robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) because **rmdir** fails for complex or deeply nested file paths.
- The logic to delete files on windows works like [Collections.retainsAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29).

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;

public class RecursiveDelete {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String dirPath = "C:" + File.separator + "dev_tools" + File.separator + "dir_to_delete";
        System.out.println("Delete folder path=" + dirPath);
        execute(dirPath);
    }

    public static void execute(String folderToDelete) throws IOException {
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        File emptyFolder = createEmptyDirectory();
        if (isWindows(os)) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c robocopy " + emptyFolder + " " + folderToDelete + " /purge & rmdir " + folderToDelete);
        } else if (isUnix(os) || isMac(os) || isSolaris(os)) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -r -f  " + folderToDelete);
        }
    }

    private static File createEmptyDirectory() {
        File emptyFolder = new File("EmptyFolder");
        if (!emptyFolder.exists()) {
            boolean isCreated = emptyFolder.mkdir();
            System.out.println("Is empty folder created ?" + isCreated);
            System.out.println("EmptyFolder path" + emptyFolder.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        return emptyFolder;
    }

    public static boolean isWindows(String os) {
        return (os.contains("win"));
    }

    public static boolean isUnix(String os) {
        return (os.contains("nix") || os.contains("aix") || os.contains("nux"));
    }

    public static boolean isSolaris(String os) {
        return (os.contains("sunos"));
    }

    public static boolean isMac(String os) {
        return (os.contains("mac"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. This uses the same File.listFiles and delete(). So not going to improve performance.

Comment: Just check the local copy of src code and realize that one of our team member had tweeked the library to perform some optimization for the in house file system developed and used by us. I also updated my answer

Comment: @sol4me performance boost is the only concern for me. I wouldn't mind to have 10 lines of code in place of adding a new jar file for apache commons

Comment: @sol4me Can you let me know what kind of optimization your team member had done ?

Comment: @hop I updated my answer

Comment: @sol4me +1. This is super fast. But, this won't help in deleting the file in a remote machine right? As  Runtime.getRuntime() is the server and not the machine I want to delete the file from. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @hop you are right, but can't you just invoke this code under the hood on server by creating some service like htpp://somedomain.com/deleteService
and pass it the directory name which you want to delete like htpp://somedomain.com/deleteService?dirToDelete=foo